# VBA - Certain Data Only Visible After Second Run

Tags: excel, vba

This code below does the following:

1. Copies specific rows from "source" sheet
2. Pastes the rows in "target" sheet
3. Does a count of the "types" (Column E) and inserts the count into Column J

The issue I have is by step 3. What the macro is supposed to do is:

1. Column I, Rows 3 - 5 --> Insert the Column Headings "Defect",
   "System", "Script"
2. Perform a CountIf function of Column E on each of the criteria in
   Column I
3. Output the value (counted number) in Column J, in the respective
   rows  alongside Column I

For example:

- Column I, Row 3 --> Defect
- Column J, Row 3 --> Count of the amount of times "Defect" occurs in
  Column E

However, what seems to be happening is this:

1. Column I is populated with the correct criteria
2. CountIf is performed (what appears to be correctly) and inserts
   the values in Column J
3. As the values are inserted, the criteria in Column I is erased
   and all I have left are the number values in Column J

Now if I run the macro a second time, then it performs as expected and I cannot understand why.

Also, there are no "Defect" entries in Column E, so the value is 0. But on the first run, you don't see 0, it's just blank. On the second run, it shows the value 0.

```
Sub Copy()

    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim i As Long, J As Long, K As Long, x As Long, count As Long
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim element As Variant, myarray As Variant

    myarray = Array("Defect", "System", "Script")

    i = Worksheets("source").UsedRange.Rows.count
    J = Worksheets("target").UsedRange.Rows.count

    count = 3

    Set y = Workbooks("myWKBK.xlsm")

    Set ws1 = y.Sheets("target")

    If J = 1 Then

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("target").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0

    End If

    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Set xRg = Worksheets("source").Range("E3:E" & lngLastRow & i)

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ws1

        'Assign name to columns where values will be pasted
        .Range("$B$2").Value = "ID"
        .Range("$C$2").Value = "Status"
        .Range("$D$2").Value = "Description"
        .Range("$E$2").Value = "Type"
        .Range("$F$2").Value = "Folder"
        .Range("$G$2").Value = "Defect ID"
        .Range("$I$2").Value = "Type"
        .Range("$I$3").Value = "Defect"
        .Range("$I$4").Value = "System"
        .Range("$I$5").Value = "Script"
        .Range("$J$2").Value = "Count"

    End With

    For Each element In myarray

        For K = 1 To xRg.count

            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = element Then

                LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & LastRow)

                J = J + 1

            End If

        Next

        x = Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

        Range("J" & count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E3:E" & x), element)

        count = count + 1

    Next element

    ws1.Columns("B:J").AutoFit

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

***EDIT:***

It's probably well worth mentioning that the below sub on its own works just fine:

```
Sub CountIf()

    Dim element As Variant
    Dim myarray As Variant

    myarray = Array("Defect", "System", "Script")

    Dim count As Long

    count = 3

    For Each element In myarray

        Dim x As Long
        x = Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("J" & count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E3:E" & x), element)

        count = count + 1

    Next element

End Sub
```

This function only performs the CountIf on its own and works exactly as expected.

Comment: Remove the `On Error Resume Next` - it is hiding the errors you are experiencing and makes the debugging a real challenge. If there is an error, it is probably the reason for the needed values on the second run.

Comment: You might want to update your question to include all necessary data that the problem can be reproduced. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This is a really beautiful part of your code:

```
Set xRg = Worksheets("source").Range("E3:E" & lngLastRow & i)
```

It sets correctly the parent worksheet of the `Range` object, thus VBA knows where to look at. However, for some reasons, it is not always like this. Take a look at these lines:

```
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
x = Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("J" & count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E3:E" & x), element)
```

where the worksheet is not set. Thus, it takes either the `ActiveSheet` or the worksheet, in which the code is (if it is in a worksheet and not in a module). Try to rewrite it, following the beautiful part of your code, e.g., defining the worksheet:

```
With Worksheet("SomeName")
    lngLastRow = .Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    x = .Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("J" & count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E3:E" & x), element)
End With
```

---

As a next step to debug, try to remove `On Error Resume Next`, because it ignores the errors in the applications and may provide false results due to this.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have removed the On Error Resume Next and I have updated the code as suggested above. However, it is still doing the same thing. I have edited my post as well which could perhaps be of some use.